# npm showing severity vulnerabilities Laravel

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-5, npm

npm showing severity vulnerabilities, but using

```
npm chache clear
npm cache clear --force
npm audit fix
npm install
```

I have tried all of them but none of these solving my problem, please give some idea how I can solve it?

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 1505 packages from 755 contributors and audited 18951 packages in 378.007s
found 11 moderate severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Running `npm audit fix` results

```
>npm audit fix npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) up to date in 118.757s fixed 0 of 11 vulnerabilities in 18990 scanned packages 11 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated
```

and my package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    },
    "dependencies": []
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `npm audit`?

Comment: @Fjarlaegur I have edited my question, please look at it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current Laravel package.json has this vulnerabilities because of `hoek` and `tunnel-agent`. `laravel-mix` is using the packages and load them through their package.json.

See more information about the issues here:
https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/566
https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/598

If you remove `"laravel-mix": "^2.0"`, the vulnerabilities are gone, but you can't use Laravel Mix any more.

As per discussion [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/pull/1471), I think the issue is fixed.

Comment: How you know "laravel-mix": "^2.0" is using infected version and not version 4.2.1, 5.0.3 or later, as these version are not having that problem, so now I need to confirm if laravel-mix is using infected version and in some way it can be changed to not infected version.

Comment: By the way, I have something in a github issue related to this and trying to implement this, I hope that will give some idea.

Comment: just run `npm audit` and you get a list of all affected packages and the path to your origin package in your last package.json.

From my point of view, you can't change this by yourself, because you have to find a alternative package for them. BUT it is not a big deal for production, because `laravel-mix` is only used for development and compiling scripts/stylesheets. However, your application wouldn't have any npm related security issues from the npm audit.

Comment: Please look at [this](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1633), I am trying to use suggestion from it.

Comment: I have just tried `npm install hoek@5.0.3 --save`, let's see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: According [this] (https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/566) noek 5.0.3 has not this issue, but after changing to it too, not solving the issue, it is still showing 11  moderate severity vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

if someone is still interested to solve this issue, I google it and found this solution

append this key value to the scripts section in "package.json" file

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions", // <-- appended
},
```

then add a new section after the "scripts" section as below

```
"resolutions": { // <-- appended
    "yargs-parser": "^18.1.3" 
},
```

now save the file and run "npm install", the vulnerabilities are gone :)

Comment: Thank you Medo, I hope it will be helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

That means, you have 11 severity vulnerabilities in your downloaded packages.

Run `npm audit` and it will show you which packages are affected. Then check clearly, if the author has provided an update. If not, you can fix it by yourself, which can be very hard because you're not deep in their sources...

However, most of the up-to-date packages provide fixed in newer versions.

Comment: Already tried this and then only I have posted when it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Once again, not your package has vulnerabilities, your dependencies have some. You have two solutions: fix it by yourself or kick it out....

Comment: I mean, do not use affected packages and try to use alternatives. Because your vulnerabilities came from some `npm install {package}` commands.

Comment: There is nothing much, now my package.json has only default packages that laravel includes during installation and I would like to use those, so I can not replace them with something else. I am trying to repair them or replace those with new files and both are failing still now, can you please give some idea to achieve that?

Comment: I have just edited my question with more details, please look at it again.

Comment: The problem is `"laravel-mix": "^2.0"`, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

You can install lastest npm version. The vulnerabilities alerts will be gone.